# Asked to assist when company in administration (UK)

Tags: united-kingdom

A friend of mine works (worked) for a company that has gone into administration (in the UK).  She has been asked to still come to the office for a few days to help out with the accounts.

I was just wondering if this is allowed, legally? But thinking about it, someone with knowledge of the company systems and procedures should be able to help close the account, but albeit under the watchful eye of the... receivers(?), and not asked to do anything without their knowledge?

Should she get advice from somewhere?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.  What is the concern?

Answer (score 1):

Unless her employment has been terminated by the Administrator she is still an employee of the company and is obliged to follow its lawful and reasonable requests. She would, of course, be entitled to payment of her salary and conditions for the period for which she "helps out".